Can we make a large branched/distorted wave pattern like this in Affinity Designer?
I want to create a large pattern, that I can use as a texture in a really big shape. Creating a random large pattern manually, equal to the size (and at high density) of target shape would be time consuming.
In my case, I need this distorted wave pattern (in the screenshot, the curve group which is repeated). Note that waves are not consistent. They are broken/branched at random distances.
I thought maybe I can create a small Style and then repeat it. It would kind of work, (especially if I could refine it by altering the four edges of pattern so each repetition is at sync, but that is a bit tedious and I'm not sure it would still look seamless). Here's how I tried:

However, I'm interested in knowing if it's actually possible to create a large procedural pattern using various features? So that you don't have to manually create and repeat pattern (a small portion) to get a big one. Like you design the pattern you need at the same size/density you need for your project.
I also tried Photo app and using straight strokes and using a noise displacement map, but it also altered the width of each stroke, which I don't need.

I'm not an Affinity Design user, but what you are looking for is a method create seamless pattern tiles.  I found this tutorial for you.

@BillyKerr I ended up using that technique for now. But I was interested in a technique that the user posted in the answer.

Get Inkscape. You can paste items between Inkscape and Affinity Designer as long as the items are paths with no unexpanded effects. The only hitch is that the programs use different internal length units, so the pasted items are scaled.
In Inkscape you can fill as big area as wanted with the Sprayer. Prepare a bunch of separate approximately horizontal lines and curves. The sprayer picks items from the selection randomly and scatters them. Do not allow rotation nor overlapping. But allow scattering and scaling.
You can roughen the spraying result by combining all sprayed paths and by applying to the combined path roughening effect "Roughen".
Apply Path > Object to Path to expand the effect. Make the paths free by applying Path > Break Apart.
This method makes easily hundreds of a mostly horizontal, but more or less randomized paths. An example:

If you need branches and other complexities you must have them as groups in the selection for spraying.
This method unfortunately makes only randomized individual paths. Behind them there's no "big picture" - for example a 3D surface or a growth process. To make it look somehow organic you need something much finer that this.
